# VBA run-time Error 9: subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a vba to extract the url from a column of hyperlinked texts:

```
Sub RemoveHyperlinks()
Dim Cell As Range

Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 1
Set Cell = Workbooks("Company_List.xlms").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

i = 0

Do Until i = Cell.Hyperlinks.Count
If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
Workbooks("Company_List.xlms").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 1).Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
i = i + 1
k = k + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

And the runtime error 9 occurs at the line:

> Set Cell = Workbooks("Company_List.xlms").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

Can anyone help with this? The Workbook name and Sheet name is correct, and my column data starts at A1 with heading title of column.

EDIT (2 Apr 2017): 
This piece of code has another error as it generated a list of url that appears to be the first one on the list. The entire list looks the same, but clicking through to each one would bring me to the correct hyperlink. I would like to have the list to have all the correct respective urls, how should I edit this code?

EDIT: 
I found the error, it should be 
Workbooks("Company_List.xlms").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 1).Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(**k**).Address

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xlsm` instead of `xlms`?

Comment: Oh yes it worked! thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Workbooks("Company_List.xlms").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange` returns `subscript out of range` then there is either not a workbook named "Company_List.xlms" in `Workbooks` or there is not a sheet named "Sheet1" in that workbook.

I suspect the first since the name is strange and should be "Company_List.xlsm" instead.